# Calculating average based on column values

Tags: r

[image]

I have a dataset that has a variable ColumnStart that identifies the first column to calculate an average. I have a second variable ColumnEnd that identifies the last column in that calculation. For the first row I would like to calculate the average of the values from column 5 to column 9. the second row from column 6 to 11, etc.

The output would be:

[image]

Here is the updated dput from R:

```
structure(list(ID = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), ShortID = c("452L", 
"3L", "4L", "324L"), Name = c("PS1", "PS2", "PS3", "PS4"), Route = 
c("Internal", 
"External", "Internal", "Internal"), ColumnStart = c(7L, 7L, 
9L, 8L), ColumnEnd = c(9L, 11L, 13L, 10L), Date1 = c(1L, 5L, 
13L, 4L), Date2 = c(2L, 6L, 45L, 3L), Date3 = c(3L, 7L, 23L, 
2L), Date4 = c(4L, 8L, 65L, 1L), Date5 = c(5L, 8L, 34L, 3L), 
Date6 = c(6L, 9L, 23L, 5L), Date7 = c(7L, 6L, 54L, 6L), Date8 = c(7L, 
6L, 1L, 7L), Date9 = c(8L, 9L, 3L, 8L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"ShortID", "Name", "Route", "ColumnStart", "ColumnEnd", "Date1", 
"Date2", "Date3", "Date4", "Date5", "Date6", "Date7", "Date8", 
"Date9"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(ID = 
structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ShortID = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Route = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), ColumnStart = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), ColumnEnd = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("ID", "ShortID", "Name", "Route", 
"ColumnStart", "ColumnEnd", "Date1", "Date2", "Date3", "Date4", 
"Date5", "Date6", "Date7", "Date8", "Date9")), default = structure(list(), 
class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R solution that drops non-numeric columns before calculating the mean:

```
df$ave2 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    y <- as.numeric(x[seq.int(x['ColumnStart'], x['ColumnEnd'])])
    mean(y[!is.na(y)])
    })

df
# A tibble: 4 x 16
  ID    ShortID Name  Route    ColumnStart ColumnEnd Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 Date5 Date6 Date7 Date8 Date9 Average
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>          <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
1 AAA   452L    PS1   Internal           7         9     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     7     8     2  
2 BBB   3L      PS2   External           7        11     5     6     7     8     8     9     6     6     9     6.8
3 CCC   4L      PS3   Internal           9        13    13    45    23    65    34    23    54     1     3    39.8
4 DDD   324L    PS4   Internal           8        10     4     3     2     1     3     5     6     7     8     2
```

`as.numeric` tries to convert the values to `numeric`. If it cannot, then it returns `NA`. We then drop `NA` values and calculate the `mean`.

---

Here's a one line version that works the same but uses `na.omit` to strip out `NA` values before calculating the mean:

```
df$Average <- apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(na.omit(as.numeric(x[seq.int(x['ColumnStart'], x['ColumnEnd'])]))))
```

Comment: Hi divibisan, The function works when the only columns in the dataset are the ColumnStart and ColumnEnd and the data i want to find the average of. When I remove identifing variables such as Name and ID the code works. My full data set has a number of identifier variables as well. The ColumnStart and ColumnEnd data do not have decimal values, they are all whole numbers.

Comment: They refer to the indices of the columns to take. I believe the error that I'm getting is due to the function reading every column for each row and not all the columns are numeric or logical. The identifier columns are in text. Is there a way to limit the apply function to only the numerical columns?

Comment: So you want it to take the mean of all columns of type `numeric` between the 2 indices?

Answer (score 1):

Another method, not necessarily suggested

```
rowMeans(df*NA^!(col(df) >= df$ColumnStart & col(df) <= df$ColumnEnd), 
         na.rm = T)
# [1] 3.000000 7.142857 5.000000 3.333333 6.500000
```

Explanation:

`col(df) >= df$ColumnStart & col(df) <= df$ColumnEnd` is a matrix which is `TRUE` at the (i, j) indices matching the `ColumnStart`, `ColumnEnd` specification

`NA^!(col(df) >= df$ColumnStart & col(df) <= df$ColumnEnd)` is a matrix which is `1` at the places where the above matrix is `TRUE` and `NA` everywhere else. Mutiplying this by `df` gives a matrix which is the same as `df` except all elements whose indices don't match the `ColumnStart` and `ColumnEnd` specification are `NA`

Now we can just take the `rowMeans` of that, with `na.rm = T` to get the desired result